# I tried crypto-js but the output is not correct, please see my code and correct me where I am wrong

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, hash, cryptojs

I have a simple_crypt function in my backend which is working properly, now what I want is to make a similar function for javascript which for exactly the same as the php one.
So I have researched and got the CryptoJS library, my 'Key' and 'iv' values are correct as compared to the PHP one but when I encrypt my string the output is totally different.

This is my working PHP code and I want to convert this into javascript.

```
<?php 

 function simple_crypt( $string ) {

  $secret_key = '1234567890';
  $secret_iv = '0987654321';
  $output = false;
  $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC"; 
  $key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
  $iv = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );

  echo "Key : ".$key."<br>";
  echo "iv : ".$iv."<br>";

  $output = openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );

  return $output;
 }


   $e =  simple_crypt("text");
   echo $e;
   echo "<br>";


?>
```

This is my JS code in which I am getting the issue, please have a look and tell me where I am wrong in this js code.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-nOQuvD9nKirvxDdvQ9OMqe2dgapbPB7vYAMrzJihw5m+aNcf0dX53m6YxM4LgA9u8e9eg9QX+/+mPu8kCNpV2A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function simple_crypt(string) {

    var secret_key, secret_iv, output, key, iv;

    secret_key = '1234567890';
    secret_iv = '0987654321';
    output = false;

   

    key = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString();
    iv = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substr(0, 16);

    console.log("key",key);
    console.log("iv",iv);


      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, {iv: iv});
      return (encrypted.toString());
}

console.log(simple_crypt("text"));

</script>
```

Here is the output:
PHP: *T4F65n4AVlmkkb5LLFhRIQ==*
JS: *U2FsdGVkX18HJGpPYZPm6crBcxA7TfbZZ9Sc/4qHGBk=*

Comment: Here is the output

PHP : T4F65n4AVlmkkb5LLFhRIQ==

Comment: JS : U2FsdGVkX18HJGpPYZPm6crBcxA7TfbZZ9Sc/4qHGBk=

Answer (score 2):

So that both codes produces the same result, the key and IV in the NodeJS Code must be the same as in the PHP code and passed as `WordArray`s. For this, the key and IV you have generated must be further processed as follows:

```
key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key.substr(0, 32));
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
```

In the PHP code, the SHA256 hash is returned as hex string. With hex encoding the number of bytes doubles, i.e. a SHA256 hash is hex encoded 64 bytes. PHP *implicitly* considers only the first 32 bytes regarding the key for AES-256, i.e. ignores the last 32 bytes. In the CryptoJS code this must happen *explicitly* (for the IV this happens, but for the key this is missing).
By parsing with the UTF8 encoder, key and IV are converted into `WordArray`s. If the key is passed as a string (as in the code posted in the question), then CryptoJS interprets the value as a password and uses a key derivation function to derive key and IV (which is incompatible with the logic in the PHP code).

With the above changes, the CryptoJS code gives the same result as the PHP code:

```js
function simple_crypt(string) {

    var secret_key, secret_iv, output, key, iv;

    secret_key = '1234567890';
    secret_iv = '0987654321';
    output = false;

    key = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_key).toString();
    iv = CryptoJS.SHA256(secret_iv).toString().substr(0, 16);

    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key.substr(0, 32));
    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);

    console.log("key",key.toString());
    console.log("iv",iv.toString());

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, {iv: iv});
    return (encrypted.toString());
}

console.log(simple_crypt("text")); // T4F65n4AVlmkkb5LLFhRIQ==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Please note the following:

- Using SHA256 to derive the key from a password is insecure. For this purpose, a reliable key derivation function such as PBKDF2 should be used.
- For security reasons, a key/IV pair may only be applied once. Therefore, the IV is usually randomly generated for each encryption. The IV is not a secret and is commonly sent to the recipient along with the ciphertext (usually prepended). Alternatively, the IV can be derived together with the key using a KDF (in combination with a randomly generated salt).

Comment: Thank Topaco for such a great help, your solution works as I want.

Comment: A True THANK from my HEART